# How to show the Date Range using R

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm really new at using `R`. I'm trying to do some basic stuff with a dataset. I have a dataset with just one column (`date`) that has the dates that participants filled in a survey:

```
11/11/2015
11/11/2015
11/11/2015
11/11/2015
11/11/2015
11/11/2015
11/11/2015
11/11/2015
27/11/2015
27/11/2015
etc (there are about 180 more responses)
```

So far I have done:

```
NUdates <- nrow(unique(date))
```

This shows me that there are 12 unique dates based on the responses

The next thing that I want to do is only return the earliest and latest date so I would have objects:

```
Emonth # (this would be the earliest month that a participant filled out the survey)
Lmonth # (this would be the latest month that a participant filled out he survey)
Year   # (this would be the year the surveys were filled out)
```

Then using markdown I would be able to say:

> participants completed surveys on `r (NUdates)` days between `r (Emonth)`and `r (Lmonth)` in `r (year)`.

Comment: I doubt the `?range` function will cut it here. Have you tried `?min` or `?max` ?

Comment: Nope `range` function does not work, at least not with the format that the dates are in, nor will `min` `max` for the same reasons: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables

Comment: Try wrapping it with as.date. Look I can help you to solve your Q, but you need to provide us with a reproducible example. We don't have time here to guess your data and manually create a variable. So before you ask a Q, please read the rules.

Comment: The function name is `as.Date`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
txt <- "11/11/2015
11/11/2015
11/11/2015
11/11/2015
11/11/2015
11/11/2015
11/11/2015
11/11/2015
27/11/2015
27/11/2015"

> dates <- as.Date(scan(text=txt, what=""), format="%d/%m/%Y")

Read 10 items
> dates
 [1] "2015-11-11" "2015-11-11" "2015-11-11" "2015-11-11" "2015-11-11"
 [6] "2015-11-11" "2015-11-11" "2015-11-11" "2015-11-27" "2015-11-27"
)
```

To get the difference between objects of Date class one can use the `-` operator.

```
>  max(dates) - min(dates) 
Time difference of 16 days
```

To remove the extraneous material you can use `unclass`:

```
dput(max(dates) - min(dates))
structure(0, units = "days", class = "difftime")

unclass(max(dates) - min(dates))
[1] 16
attr(,"units")
[1] "days"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, exactly what I needed. I had tried to use the as.Date function but was incorrectly specifying the format. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is assuming you have your unique dates found out in the sequence.
Next steps - 
1) Make sure your dates are in sorted order. You can do so by -

```
table <- table[order(table$Date),]
```

table is the dataframe of your unique dates. 
2)Using package [timeDate](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeDate/timeDate.pdf) 
Functions timeFirstDayInMonth() and timeLastDayInMonth() are what you'd need.

```
start_date <- timeFirstDayInMonth(table$Date[1])                #First Date Of First Occuring Month
end_date <- timeLastDayInMonth(table$Date[nrow(table)-1])       #Last Date Of Last Occuring Month
```

3) You can finally find Emonth and Lmonth

```
Emonth <- format(start_date, format = "%B")        #Full Month name
```

or

```
Lmonth <- format(end_date, format = "%m")        #Decimal Month
```